# search from child collection contains the keyword from parent and child collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am facing a problem with getting data from database using parent child relationship collections.
Here is my collection structure --
-post
---post cloth : brand id from brands collections
-----brand

Now I am getting data from post and post cloth with keyword search from post cloth and brand table if any key matches from post cloth and brand. Till post cloth it is working fine along with keyword search in or condition, Now I also need to search from brand and return the result if keyword contains in brand as well.
here are my cases --

1. data returned : if any of post_cloths keys matches the keyword searched
2. data returned : if any of the post_cloths keys matches the keyword OR lookup with brand name matches the keyword
3. data returned : if all keys from post_cloths not matches the keyword but lookup with brand name matches the keyword
4. data not returned : if no keys from post_cloths matches the keyword and also lookup with brand name not matches the keyword

Here is my code :

```
var page = 0;
if (req.query.page >= 0) {
    page = req.query.page;
}
let filter = { 'totalCloth': { $gte: 1 } };
if (req.query.user != null && req.query.user != '') {
    filter.createdBy = ObjectID(req.query.user);
}
console.log(filter);
var searchQuery = [];
var brandSearchQuery = [];
if (req.query.keyword != null && req.query.keyword != '') {
    console.log(req.query.keyword);
    keyword = req.query.keyword;
    searchQuery = [
        {
            $regexFind: {
                input: '$category',
                regex: new RegExp(keyword),
                options: 'i',
            },
        },
        {
            $regexFind: {
                input: '$color',
                regex: new RegExp(keyword),
                options: 'i',
            },
        },
        {
            $regexFind: {
                input: '$country',
                regex: new RegExp(keyword),
                options: 'i',
            },
        },
        {
            $regexFind: {
                input: '$size',
                regex: new RegExp(keyword),
                options: 'i',
            },
        },
        {
            $regexFind: {
                input: '$clothMaterial',
                regex: new RegExp(keyword),
                options: 'i',
            },
        },
    ];
    brandSearchQuery = [
        {
            $regexFind: {
                input: '$name',
                regex: new RegExp(keyword),
                options: 'i',
            },
        },
    ];
} else {
    searchQuery = [{}];
    brandSearchQuery = [{}];
}
// get the post details
// PostModel.find(filter).countDocuments().then(countPosts => {
PostModel.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'post_cloths',
            let: { postId: '$_id' },
            pipeline: [
                //lookup for brand
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: 'brands',
                        let: { brandId: '$brandId' },
                        pipeline: [
                            {
                                $match: {
                                    $expr:
                                        {
                                            $and:
                                                [
                                                    { $eq: ['$_id', '$$brandId'] },
                                                    { $or: brandSearchQuery },
                                                ],
                                        },
                                },
                            },
                        ],
                        as: 'brand',
                    },
                },
                //end of brand lookup
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $and:
                                [
                                    { $eq: ['$postId', '$$postId'] },
                                    {
                                        $or: searchQuery,
                                    },
                                ],
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        totalBrands: { $size: '$brand' },
                    },
                },
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr:
                            { $or: [{ $match: { totalBrands: { $gte: 1 } } }] },
                    },
                },
            ],
            as: 'postCloth',
        },
    },
    {
        $project: {
            image: 1,
            createdAt: 1,
            createdBy: 1,
            mediaUrl: {
                $concat: [process.env.PROJECT_URL + '/files/', '$image'],
            },
            totalCloth: { $size: '$postCloth' },
        },
    },
    //check for post cloth object if length is greater than equals to 1
    {
        $match: filter,
    },

    { $skip: 12 * page },
    { $limit: 12 },
    { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
]).exec(function(err, post) {
    return apiResponse.successResponseWithData(res, 'Successful', post);
});
```

I am getting data properly, but not while searching from brand. Please suggest how we can search the data from the cases given. there is simple keyword search.

Thanks in advance

Comment: post some example documents of all collections and expected result.

Comment: This is so difficult to understand, can you explain it with examples?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with you're main's `$lookup`'s pipeline:

first you start with the `brand` `$lookup`, which i'll assume works ( if you provide schema's for your collections it would be easy to verify), however right after that `$lookup` you do this:

```
{
    $match: {
        $expr:
            {
                $and:
                    [
                        { $eq: ['$postId', '$$postId'] },
                        {
                            $or: searchQuery,
                        },
                    ],
            },
    },
},
```

This means if the `searchQuery` fails even if a brand exists the document will be filtered out, you should change it to:

```
{
    $match: {
        $expr:
            {
                $and:
                    [
                        { $eq: ['$postId', '$$postId'] },
                        {
                            $or: [
                                {
                                    $or: searchQuery
                                },
                                {
                                    $gt: [{$size: "$brand"}, 0]
                                }
                            ],
                        },
                    ],
            },
    },
},
```

Now this will also matched documents that have any brands in the `brand` field, meaning the brand matched the nested `$lookup`, you can then drop the next 2 stages that check for the brand size.

I also recommend that you move the `$eq` for the `postId` to the start of the `$lookup`, this will improve performance immensely, after all the changes the entire pipeline would look like:

```
PostModel.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'post_cloths',
            let: { postId: '$_id' },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: { $eq: ['$postId', '$$postId'] },
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: 'brands',
                        let: { brandId: '$brandId' },
                        pipeline: [
                            {
                                $match: {
                                    $expr:
                                        {
                                            $and:
                                                [
                                                    { $eq: ['$_id', '$$brandId'] },
                                                    { $or: brandSearchQuery },
                                                ],
                                        },
                                },
                            },
                        ],
                        as: 'brand',
                    },
                },
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $and:
                                [

                                    {
                                        $or: [
                                            {
                                                $or: searchQuery,
                                            },
                                            {
                                                $gt: [{ $size: '$brand' }, 0],
                                            },
                                        ],
                                    },
                                ],
                        },
                    },
                },
            ],
            as: 'postCloth',
        },
    },
    {
        $project: {
            image: 1,
            createdAt: 1,
            createdBy: 1,
            mediaUrl: {
                $concat: [process.env.PROJECT_URL + '/files/', '$image'],
            },
            totalCloth: { $size: '$postCloth' },
        },
    },
    {
        $match: filter,
    },
    { $skip: 12 * page },
    { $limit: 12 },
    { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
])
```